# Weird derivative with respect to inverse temperature identity in Tong's statistical physics lecture notes

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, differentiation, calculus

While reading David Tong's Statistical Physics lecture notes (https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html) I came across this weird identity in page 26 (at the end of the 1.3.4 free energy subsection)

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} = -k_B T^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial T}
$$

whereas $ \beta $ is as usual $ \frac{1}{k_B T} $. I can't wrap my head around this identity, so I would appreciate any help in understanding this.

Comment: It is just the chain rule of differentiation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...I came across this weird identity...
>
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} = -k_B T^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial T}
> $$

This is just the chain rule of differentiation.

> whereas $ \beta $ is as usual $ \frac{1}{k_B T} $...

Yes, so that means that
$$
\frac{dT}{d\beta} = -k_B T^2
$$

And therefore:
$$
\frac{df}{d\beta} = \frac{dT}{d\beta}\frac{df}{dT} = -k_B T^2 \frac{df}{dT}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.