# Convert $\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}$ to an expression in terms of $T$, given $\beta=k_B T$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, temperature

I'm trying to calculate the average energy of the Grand Canonical partition function for a noninteracting, nonrelativistic integer spin gas. The equation of interest is $$\langle E\rangle =-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\ln\left[\frac{1}{1-e^{(\mu-\epsilon)/T}}\right].$$

where $\beta=k_BT$. I imagine that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}=\frac{\partial}{k_B\,\partial T}$, but just saying that doesn't feel right. Any advice?

Comment: Use the chain rule of calculus: $d/d\beta = (dT/d\beta) (d/dT)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird derivative with respect to inverse temperature identity in Tong's statistical physics lecture notes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/780648/)

Comment: Wait... do you really mean "given $\beta = k_B T$" or is that a typo for $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$??

Comment: And also, it should be $(\mu-\epsilon)/k_BT$ too; isn't it easier to just convert this part to depend upon $\beta$ so that this becomes a simpler thing to differentiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your expression for $\beta$ is incorrect. In fact, $\beta\neq kT$, but rather,
$$\beta=\frac{1}{kT}.$$
However, it is still straightforward to convert between derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}$ using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}=\frac{dT}{d\beta}\frac{\partial}{\partial T}=\left[\frac{d}{d\beta}\left(\frac{1}{k\beta}\right)
\right]\frac{\partial}{\partial T}=-\frac{1}{k\beta^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial T}=-kT^{2}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial T}.$$

Comment: Ah, yes that was a typo and I believe this was my problem. Thank you.